# Relationship SOQL queries using RForcecom

Tags: soql, query, relationships, rforcecom

I am trying to query two objects in salesforce via their parent-child relationship, using the R package RForcecom (read more about RForcecom [here](https://hiratake55.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/rforcecom/)).

I have successfully used RForcecom to query one object at a time, but can't tell from the documentation if it's possible to use this package to enter a relationship query. Such as:

```
    SELECT Account__c,Reporting_Period__c,Year__c,Product_Family__c
        ( SELECT ID,Transaction_Date__c,Total_Volume__c FROM Transaction__c )
    FROM Licensee_Report__c
```

All of these field and object names refer to real fields/objects and are the correct API names for our salesforce instance. This is just an example and serves to highlight the kind of multi-object query I am hoping to make.

Normally, RForcecom lets you use the function rforcecom.query() to run SOQL queries after having logged into the API within R. See the link above for more.

Currently, I'm getting an error message where I open the parentheses for the sub-query on the child object, and the message 'unexpected token: 'SELECT''

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There's a comma missing in front of your inner query. It should look like this:

```
 SELECT Account__c,Reporting_Period__c,Year__c,Product_Family__c,
        ( SELECT ID,Transaction_Date__c,Total_Volume__c FROM Transaction__c )
    FROM Licensee_Report__c
```

Comment: probably `FROM Transactions__r )`